# Google.JarResolver.ResolutionException

Tags: admob

I'm fresh to c# and unity3D. I encountered below error. Please help me. Thanks.

After import GoogleAds package. The unity project pop up below error. How to fix it? Thanks.

error message:

```
    Google.JarResolver.ResolutionException: Cannot find candidate artifact for com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.0+

  at Google.JarResolver.PlayServicesSupport.DependOn (System.String group, System.String artifact, System.String version) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 

  at AdMobDependencies..cctor () [0x00039] in D:\Unity\GuessFist\Assets\PlayServicesResolver\Editor\AdMobDependencies.cs:21 

UnityEditor.EditorAssemblies:SetLoadedEditorAssemblies(Assembly[])
```

Comment: Did Rafal answer your question correctly? If so, mark as correct please.

Answer (score 0):

Seems that you're missing `android-support-v7` jar in `Plugins/Android` directory.

You'll find instructions on how to get it here: http://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/setup.html